# How can this Jim Browning YouTuber have access to so many scammers' computers/networks?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, system-compromise

I'm frankly sick of these videos, and the only interesting part to me has nothing to do with the scam or the content of the video, but simply the fact that he is apparently somehow able to see exactly what they are doing on their screens. "Hacking"...

How is this possible? Why is it never mentioned? It's driving me insane that they keep avoiding this the most interesting topic.

One of the many examples: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mPpuUnQ6cac

He makes it seem as if he has some sort of magical, supernatural access to any computer in the world at will. It makes me extremely scared -- infinitely more so than the dumb scammers and their nonsense -- and makes me wonder if somebody is watching me type this right now...

Comment: You may be confused because he's "stringer sorting" -- he's portraying the results of a successful investigation; but he's not showing you all the failed investigations and failed reverse-hacks that came before it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How is this possible?**

Most of these scammers load software onto their victims computers and some of these tools allow for reverse connections as well. Similarly the victim may scam the scammer into opening a binary or other exploit that would give John remote access to their computers.

A lot of these scammers themselves run un-updated, un-patched often illegal versions of Windows which tend to be more susceptible to these type of exploits. Once he has a foothold to one machine he probably uses it to pivot to other machines.

**Why is it never mentioned?**

Otherwise scammers would be aware as well and less susceptible to these attacks.

**He makes it seem as if he has some sort of magical, supernatural access to any computer in the world at will.**

Not much different than running a red-team. The weakest link in security is still humans clicking on random links or opening random files. He exploits this weakness.

Comment: I don't get why some idiots downvoted my question, but I would upvote your answer if this site let me.

Comment: I didn't know that there *were* un-updated/un-patched versions of Windows since Windows 98 or so, though. Even the entire XP era was pretty aggressive about updating, and I frankly never paid for my copy. (But I would in retrospect.)